# Swift REST API call to Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am using the following code to make a call to the Azure Form Recognizer REST API for the receipt model in my iOS Swift app. This doesn't return any error codes, but the response is just empty. I have also tried this in Post Man and also get an empty response.

How do I get the data back from this API call?

```
func recognizeReceipt(imageData: Data, apiKey: String, endpoint: String) {
    
    let urlString = "\(endpoint)/formrecognizer/documentModels/prebuilt-receipt:analyze?api-version=2022-08-31"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")
    request.setValue("application/octet-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = imageData
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            print("Invalid response")
            return
        }
        
        if (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) {
            if let data = data {
                // Process the response data
                let resultString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("Result: \(resultString ?? "")")
            }
        } else {
            print("API request failed. Status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

Thank you

Comment: if in Post Man you get the same results, I would stop looking at the app for the issue, just focus on PostMan. Does postman return a 200 but no data at all?

Comment: @OneCommentMan In the body it has no data at all, in the top right of the results panel it says ‘202 Accepted’

Comment: Oh ok, so status code 202 means that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. So the API call is working as intended, unless you're expecting some kind of data even in this case. I'd advise talking to whoever is in charge of the REST APIs. But good news, nothing wrong with your code at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that once you get the success response, you must then make another call to Azure to get the results with the `Operation Location` value:

```
if let operationLocationVal = headers["operation-location"] as? String {
    print("Operation Location: \(operationLocationVal)")
}
```

Then extract the data using:

```
do {
                    
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
    let analyzeResult = json["analyzeResult"] as? [String: Any],
    let documents = analyzeResult["documents"] as? [Any],
    let document = documents.first as? [String: Any] {

    //Extract data from document here
    if let fields = document["fields"] as? [String: Any] {
        //Get total value                    
        if let total = fields["Total"] as? [String: Any],
        let totalValueNumber = total["valueNumber"] as? Double {
            print("Total Value Number: \(totalValueNumber)")
        } else {
            print("Total value unknown")
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```